# Stream tweets only if location is available

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm searching for tweets of blockchain using tweepy, for that I'm using the following code:

Auth:

```
consumerKey = ""
consumerSecret = ""
accessToken = ""
accessTokenSecret = ""

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumerKey, consumerSecret)
auth.set_access_token(accessToken, accessTokenSecret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
```

Search:

```
query = 'blockchain'
max_tweets = 5
searched_tweets = [status for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=query).items(max_tweets)]
```

One issue I'm having with this is that the coordinates are not available:

```
u'retweeted': False, u'coordinates': None, u'source':
```

Not even the location:

```
'friends_count': 191, u'location': u''
```

I want to plot this information on a map, hence I need the coordinates.

Comment: The proportion of tweets with location data enabled, from experience, seems to be very low. I'd be surprised if you got any results in a search of only 5 tweets.